# Nginx proxy_pass for '/' route only, with $http_accept

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

The reasoning behind this is that if a client requests `Content-Type: application/ld+json` from the home page of my application then the query should be redirected to an API which will serve that. So, I have something like this:

```
location / {
        if ($http_accept = 'application/ld+json') {
            proxy_pass https://api.example.org/homepage_jsonld/;
        }

        root /var/www/example.org/dist;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
```

...which results in:

```
nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block
```

Can anyone suggest how to get around this?
Ideally, I'd only need to use the proxy_pass if the route requested is '/', and to pass any other route on to the application in /var/www/example.org/dist.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be as follows:

```
location = '/' {
        if ($http_accept = 'application/ld+json') {
                rewrite "^/" /homepage_jsonld break; 
                proxy_pass https://api.example.org;
        }
      
        root /var/www/example.org/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
```

...in addition to the existing `location /` block.